# merge two dictionary lists if value is the same

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries like the ones below:

```py
a = [
    {'name': 'john', 'exam 1': 'python'},
    {'name': 'chris', 'exam 1': 'java'},
    {'name': 'newman', 'exam 1': 'C'},
    {'name': 'sebast', 'exam 1': 'C#'},
    {'name': 'penier', 'exam 1': 'python'},
    {'name': 'alex', 'exam 1': 'go'},
    {'name': 'steve', 'exam 1': 'C#'}
]

b = [
    {'name': 'john', 'exam 2': 'django'},
    {'name': 'newman', 'exam 2': 'java'},
    {'name': 'sebast', 'exam 2': 'C'},
    {'name': 'chris', 'exam 2': 'C#'}
    {'name': 'penier', 'exam 2': 'python'},
    {'name': 'steve', 'exam 2': 'go'},
    {'name': 'alex', 'exam 2': 'C#'}
]
```

I would like to merge them in one dictionary like the one below:

```py
c = [
    {'name': 'john', 'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'django'},
    {'name': 'chris', 'exam 1': 'java', 'exam 2': 'C#'},
    {'name': 'newman', 'exam 1': 'C', 'exam 2': 'java'},
    {'name': 'sebast', 'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'C'},
    {'name': 'penier', 'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'python'},
    {'name': 'alex', 'exam 1': 'go', 'exam 2': 'C#'},
    {'name': 'steve', 'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'go'}
]
```

I have tried the following:

```py
for i, j in zip(a, b):
   if i['name'] == j['name']:
      c.update(i)
```

The result I am getting is just one dictionary that adds those lines that are the same not if their location is different.

Comment: You need nested loops, not `zip()`, since the indexes aren't the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create two *lookup* dictionaries for each list and then find the *intersection*:

```
import pprint

lookup_A = {d["name"]: d for d in A}
lookup_B = {d["name"]: d for d in B}

result = [{**value, **lookup_B.get(key, {})} for key, value in lookup_A.items()]
pprint.pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'django', 'name': 'john'},
 {'exam 1': 'java', 'exam 2': 'C#', 'name': 'chris'},
 {'exam 1': 'C', 'exam 2': 'java', 'name': 'newman'},
 {'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'C', 'name': 'sebast'},
 {'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'python', 'name': 'penier'},
 {'exam 1': 'go', 'exam 2': 'C#', 'name': 'alex'},
 {'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'go', 'name': 'steve'}]
```

**UPDATE**

A simpler way to understand a list comprehension, is to do a the equivalent for-loop:

```
result= []
for key, value in lookup_A.items():
    result.append({**value, **lookup_B.get(key, {})})
```

The expression:

```
{**value, **lookup_B.get(key, {})}
```

is known as [dictionary unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/#unpackingdictionarieswiththeoperator) and it was added to Python in the version [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

Comment: Dani, Thanks for taking the time. can you explain what you are doing in result?

Comment: @user3568896 Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `pandas` you can do `merge`

```
pd.DataFrame(A).merge(pd.DataFrame(B), on='name').to_dict('records')
```

---

```
[{'name': 'john', 'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'django'},
 {'name': 'chris', 'exam 1': 'java', 'exam 2': 'C#'},
 {'name': 'newman', 'exam 1': 'C', 'exam 2': 'java'},
 {'name': 'sebast', 'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'C'},
 {'name': 'penier', 'exam 1': 'python', 'exam 2': 'python'},
 {'name': 'alex', 'exam 1': 'go', 'exam 2': 'C#'},
 {'name': 'steve', 'exam 1': 'C#', 'exam 2': 'go'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though inefficient, here's a simple approach that is easy to follow, I suppose something like this was what you had in mind with your attempt using `zip`.

```py
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if b['name'] == a['name']:
            a.update(b)
    C.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the lists and do a lookup before adding as follows:

*Benefit is greater control. Cost is O(n) where n is the length of `b`*

```
# Start off with values being a
c_dict = {x['name']:x for x in a}

# 'Upsert' from new list of dicts
for x in b:
    # You can update this to make this skip items not found in b
    # or other similar operations
    if not c_dict.get(x['name']):
         c_dict[x['name']] = x
    else:
        c_dict[x['name']].update(x)

# Finally convert to a list
c = list(c_dict.values())
```